# Inverted drawing with iOS origin at bottom left of screen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, drawing

When using SpriteKit to draw an interactive line the origin begins at the bottom left of the screen instead of the topleft of the screen. As a result my x coordinates are ok but my y coordinates are inverted. I've read about affine transformations but don't understand how to apply them. It seems like this is a common problem and my code shouldn't be far from wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you very much.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var spriteView: SKView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let scene = GameSprite(size: view.bounds.size)
        spriteView.showsDrawCount = true
        spriteView.showsFPS = true
        spriteView.showsNodeCount = true
        spriteView.ignoresSiblingOrder  = true
        scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
        scene.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0) // added since posting
        spriteView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class GameSprite: SKScene {
    var startPoint = CGPointMake(0,0)
    var endPoint = CGPointMake(0,0)
    var node = SKShapeNode();

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent     event: UIEvent) {
        if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
            startPoint = touch.locationInView(view)
        }
        node.removeFromParent()

        addNode()
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
            endPoint = touch.locationInView(view)
        }

        modifyNode(endPoint)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
            endPoint = touch.locationInView(view)
        }
        modifyNode(endPoint)
    }

    func addNode() {

        var pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

        node.path = pathToDraw;
        node.strokeColor = SKColor.redColor()
        addChild(node)
    }

    func modifyNode(point: CGPoint) {
        endPoint = point

        var pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

        node.path = pathToDraw;
        node.strokeColor = SKColor.redColor()
        node.removeFromParent()
        addChild(node)
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.motionmobs.com/blog/2015/1/15/so-you-want-to-try-spritekit Take a look here, you can actually change the origin of nodes (even root node).

Comment: I changed the code according to the article, and edited it above, and tried it out, but no luck. Maybe I've done it wrong?